# 404 error after upgrade to Struts 2.3.32

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, struts2

I upgraded Struts2 version,include

1. free-marker-2.3.22.jar
2. ognl-3.0.19.jar
3. struts2-core-2.3.32.jar
4. struts2-json-plugin-2.3.32.jar
5. struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.32.jar
6. struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.32.jar
7. xwork-core-2.3.32.jar

and added the code to struts.xml

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.mapallmatches" value="true"/>
```

I did not use freemarker but I also added the jar to the "WEB-INF/lib"

the `pom.xml` was upgraded too.

There was no Exception when the tomcat started.

but my project always showed "404",the console showed no messages.

what should I do ?

Comment: How does your question text relate to the title line?

Comment: Sry,my bad. T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys are case sensitive in properties file. The same keys are used in `struts.xml`. See docs [Class PropertyResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html).

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
```

Comment: @Volley You should accept and upvote the answer that helped you. If you don't know how to do it see http://stackoverflow.com/tour